# What's the difference between ...的 and 所...的

Tags: word-choice, usage, grammar

I believe that both of these constructions create what is called a "subordinate clause". I know that 的 can be used to specify something like:

- 我喜欢的东西 (those things which I like),
- 很远的地方 (the place which is far), and
- 跟他谈恋爱的人 (the person who he is dating)

Is it true that all these examples also work with `所...的`?

Does `所...的` carry a connotation that is not present in `...的`?

Are there circumstances where one is preferred to the other?

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell you: `很远的地方` is just `adv. + adj. + noun`, "very distant place"; and `跟他谈恋爱的人` is a little complex, `prep. + object + verb + 的 + noun`. These two kinds of structures can be hardly found corresponding 所...的 structures.

Comment: This [link](http://chinesegrammar.info/particles/suo-structural-particle/) containing some examples may help to clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`所...的` and `...的` are ***different***.

### Function of `...的`

As you have already known, `...的` can construct **adjective clause**.

> (我喜欢)+的+东西
>
> **(subject + verb) + 的 + noun** = noun + **which** + subject + verb

And in Chinese, the noun can be omitted in a clear context. In this case, `……的` constructs a **noun clause**.

> 我喜欢的（人）是你。 Who I like is you.
>
> **(subject + verb) + 的** = **what/who** + subject + verb

### Function of `所...的`

Though it's not so obvious, the function of [所](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/6240.htm) in `所...的` is

> 5.　用在动词前，与前面的“为”或“被”字相应，表示被动的意思
>
> `所` is put before a verb, corresponding to the previous `为` or `被`, indicating **passive voice**. (And `为/被` is often omitted.)

Unfortunately, many chinese verbs are either transitive or intransitive, so the sentences containing `...的` or `所...的` often look alike.

> 我爱的人 **the person who I love**
>
> (被)我所爱的人 **[literal translation] the person who is loved by me**
>
> 我讨厌的是你。 **Who I hate is you.**
>
> 我所讨厌的是你。 **[literal translation] (The person) who is hated by me is you.**

### Difference between them

Thus, the difference between the two structures is **whether it is passive voice or not**. In most cases, one can be reconstructed to another.

> Q: So, which one should I use in the xxx case?
>
> A: It depends on personal choice. Just as you didn't said *which one should be used (by me) in the xxx case?*

### EDIT: Some irreplaceable examples

There is preference in some situations. **Some idioms can only be expressed in a unique voice (active or passive).** Though this meaning of [所](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/6240.htm) `4. 用在动词前，代表接受动作的事物` is listed as a single entry, in the grammar structure, it's actually the passive voice. So I include it in the passive-only case.

***Active-Only Examples***

> **(Right)** 天杀 **的** 政府 the goddamn government = [literal translation] the government which god should kill
>
> **(Wrong)** 天 **所** 杀 **的** 政府
>
> **(Right)** 狗日 **的** 政府 the fxxking government = [literal translation] the government which dogs should fxxk
>
> **(Wrong)** 狗 **所** 日 **的** 政府

***Passive-Only Example***

> **(Right)** 你 **所** 谓 **的** 正义 your so-called justice = [literal translation] the justice which is called (only) by you
>
> **(Wrong)** 你谓 **的** 正义

`谓` is a special verb, so in the example above (well, I don't mean everywhere), it can only be in the passive voice. However, a character with the same meaning, `说`, can be in either active or passive voice.

> Both `你说的正义` and `你所说的正义` are OK.

Anyway, idioms always need to be memorized mechanically. It's difficult to find an easy rule for them.

Comment: Comments have been cleared. Just a reminder, the comments section should not be used to carry on extended discussion. These discussions should be taken to chat.

Answer (score 4):

"所" is from ancient chinese or archaic chinese,“所+ vt” just denotes the object of vt,For example,“所思在远道”，but since Sui or Tang dynasty,there have been  exceptions like “所守或非亲”，“所守"just denotes the subject of vt .

In Mandarin,“所+VT” may be followed by “的”  where you may omit 所to have a more speech-styled sentence，or may not be followed by  “的” where the sentence is consistent with archaic chinese,and you can not omit 所to have a well-formed sentence ,like "所谓清白，也就说不清楚了".In both cases,they are more formal ,less speech-styled,since "所" is from ancient chinese or archaic chinese. So，

**Question 1** Is it true that all these examples also work with 所...的?
No,since some words or sentence are  familiar-styled and used in familiar speech,if you add 所 into the sentence,it sound like joking.

**Question 2** Does 所...的 carry a connotation that is not present in ...的?
Please see what I say above

**Question 2** Are there circumstances where one is preferred to the other?
Yes,in formal circumstances，you may use 所...的;in familiar speech,we have to use only 的 without 所。

Comment: +1, orthodox explanation.